# Insert records using collection to newly added column

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm using oracle Version 
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production

I have crated a table called, xy inserted values to it and then added one more column. Now I just want to add values to newly added column. Is there any possibility to add values to new column without using update.

```
create table xy(x1 number, y1 number);

insert into xy(x1,y1) values(1, 1);
insert into xy(x1,y1) values(2, 2);
insert into xy(x1,y1) values(3, 3);

select * from xy;
     X1         Y1
---------- ----------
     1          1
     2          2
     3          3
```

Now I added, one more column to this table.

```
alter table xy add z1 number;
```

Now, I need to add values to newly added column (z1).

I tried to do it with following but inserts new rows only, Yes I understand if we use insert it will add new rows only.

```
Declare
TYPE xy_type is table of xy%rowtype index by PLS_Integer;
xyt xy_type;
x number;
y number;
Begin
select * bulk collect into xyt from xy;
x := 1;
y := xyt.count;
for i in x..y loop
  insert into xy (x1, y1, z1) values(xyt(i).x1, xyt(i).y1, i);     
End Loop;
End;
```

So, just looking if is there any alternative way without using update, may be with the help of collections or SQL.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: `Insert` will add new rows. You need to update value of the new table using the existing rows. Google down `Merge` statement for this. No need for PLSQL here

Comment: Why don't you want to use `update`? It's simple one-line statement to get your result.

Comment: Even if you were to use a collection, the rows in the table can only be 'UPDATE'ed. You can use MERGE but technically that also is going to do an update. Any particular reason you don't want to use an update?

Answer (score 1):

Use a `MERGE` statement:

```
MERGE INTO xy dst
USING ( SELECT ROWID AS rid, ROWNUM AS rn FROM xy ) src
ON ( src.RID = dst.ROWID )
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET z1 = rn;
```

It is not using the `UPDATE` statement but it will update the values in the matched rows.

Another way of doing this without an `UPDATE` would be to store all the rows in a collection then `DELETE` the rows and recreate them with the new values (but that seems like overkill just to avoid using an `UPDATE` statement).